# Problem with arithmetic sequence in List comprehension Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I write a function like this:

```
constGrid :: a -> [[a]]
constGrid c = take 3 [take 3 [i,i ..] | i <- [c,c ..]]
```

And I am calling it with:

```
print(constGrid 'a')
```

It's supposed to print

```
["aaa","aaa","aaa"]
```

or any integer or boolean replacing `'a'`.

When I comment the first line it works, but when I open it, it gives an error like this:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:17:46: error:
• No instance for (Enum a)
    arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘c, c .. ’
  Possible fix:
    add (Enum a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        constGrid :: a -> [[a]]
• In the expression: [c, c .. ]
  In a stmt of a list comprehension: i <- [c, c .. ]
  In the second argument of ‘take’, namely
    ‘[take 3 [i, i .. ] | i <- [c, c .. ]]’
```

What is the problem with my function? I am not supposed to change anything on first line.

Comment: It won't work when I make the take 4. I need flexible code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the aim is to get an infinite list of `i`s, then you want `repeat i`.

But if you only ever want a finite number, note that `replicate n i` is a shorter way of saying `take n (repeat i)`

Both of these will work without any constraint on the type of the list elements - whereas, as you've discovered, the "range" notation requires `Enum`.

Answer (score 4):

The code as given doesn't compile because the type annotation doesn't fit the inferred type of the expression.

The type annotation is actually optional, so you can omit it. If you do that, you can load the code in GHCi and ask what the type is:

```
> :t constGrid
constGrid :: Enum a => a -> [[a]]
```

That fits the error message, which said:

```
Possible fix:
  add (Enum a) to the context of
    the type signature for:
      constGrid :: forall a. a -> [[a]]
```

Now do that:

```
constGrid :: Enum a => a -> [[a]]
constGrid c = take 3 [take 3 [i,i ..] | i <- [c,c ..]]
```

The code now compiles and works as intended:

```
> constGrid 'a'
["aaa","aaa","aaa"]
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAICS the list `[i,i ..]` cannot be build since the compiler does not know enough about the type of `i`. That is, it cannot infer that `i` is an `Enum` so it does not know how to continue that sequence.

Comment: I am a total noob on Haskell. I am not sure what to do to fix it. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Play it at the keyboard.

```
-- movement 1. the theme.
take 1 [1,1 ..] == [1]
take 2 [1,1 ..] == [1,1]
take 3 [1,1 ..] == [1,1,1]

-- movement 2. development.
[1 | i <- [1]]  == [1]
[1 | i <- [1,1]]  == [1,1]
[1 | i <- [1,1,1]]  == [1,1,1]

-- movement 3. counterpoint.
take 1 [1,2 ..] == [1]
take 2 [1,2 ..] == [1,2]
take 3 [1,2 ..] == [1,2,3]

-- movement 4. coda.
[1 | i <- [1]]  == [1]
[1 | i <- [1,2]]  == [1,1]
[1 | i <- [1,2,3]]  == [1,1,1]
```

Ergo,

```
[1 | i <- take n [1,2 ..]]  ==  [1, ....   -- or 'a' etc. instead of 1

[ [1 | i <- take n [1,2 ..]] 
  | i <- take n [1,2 ..] ]  ==  [[1, ....  -- or 'a' etc. instead of 1
```

Here the counting concern and the output concern are separated. The problem with your function was that you used your output element both for counting and for output. But you really ought to count just with `Integer`s.

`take n [1,2 ..]` can also be written as `[1,2..n]` or just `[1..n]`.

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea how it is fixed but fixed version is this.

```
constGrid :: a -> [[a]] 
constGrid c = take 3 [map (\x-> i) take 3 [1,1 .. 1] | map (\x-> c) [1,1 .. 1]]
```